Laravel Livewire DOM issues with custom JS
I am new to Laravel Livewire. I am trying to keep a form field where I am using the intlTelInput JS library to add the country code before the phone number.
I have added the JS code in app.js, which is something like this.
import intlTelInput from 'intl-tel-input';
const elementsWithPhoneId = document.querySelectorAll('[id="phone"]');
elementsWithPhoneId.forEach(element => {

    const iti = intlTelInput(element, {
        initialCountry: "bh",
        separateDialCode: true,
        onlyCountries: ['bh', 'sa', 'ae', 'qa', 'kw', 'om', 'us', 'gb'],
        utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@21.1.1/build/js/utils.js",
    });
});

Fields in the component looks like this
<div class="flex flex-wrap lg:flex-nowrap justify-center w-full">
    <div class="w-full py-2 lg:w-1/2 md:w-1/2 px-2 grid grid-cols-1">
        <label for="inputC1P1" class="w-full font-medium py-1">Primary Phone : <span class="text-red-600"> *</span></label>
        <input
            required
            type="tel"
            class="form-input border border-1 rounded-md w-full my-1 border-gray-300 shadow-md hover:transition-all"
            id="phone"
            placeholder="3344 5566"
            wire:model.blur="C1PrimaryContact"
        />
        <div>
            @error('C1PrimaryContact') <p class="text-red-600 font-light text-xs antialiased italic">{{ $message }}</p>  @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full py-2 lg:w-1/2 md:w-1/2 px-2 grid grid-cols-1">
        <label for="inputC1P2" class="w-full font-medium py-1">Secondary Phone :</label>
        <input
            type="tel"
            class="form-input border border-1 rounded-md w-full my-1 border-gray-300 shadow-md hover:transition-all"
            id="phone"
            placeholder="3344 5566"
            wire:model.blur="C1SecondaryContact"
        />
        <div>
            @error('C1SecondaryContact') <p class="text-red-600 font-light text-xs antialiased italic">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

It loads perfectly fine when a component loads for the first time. Once we change something or submit the form, however, it stops working, and the entire app.js stops working.
I have done some alternatives like adding the JS code inside of the component with @script @endscript blade directives or even applied.
document.addEventListener('livewire:init', () => {})


So far, something else is needed. Is there anything I am missing, or do I need to configure something in Livewire settings?

You can avoid the DOM update by Livewire using wire:ignore for example surrounding the inputs with a <div>:
<div class="w-full py-2 lg:w-1/2 md:w-1/2 px-2 grid grid-cols-1">

    <label .... > .... </label>
    
    <div class="...." wire:ignore>
       <input .... />
    <div>

    .....


Note that you are assigning the same id to both the inputs: this is not a good practice, the id must be unique. You can choose another attribute to select the inputs, for example:
const elementsWithPhoneId = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=tel]");

a specific class can be another option.
Also the for attributes of your labels do not match the related input id.
Edit
Looking at your repository, I can see that you use redirectRoute() with the navigate: true option. This causes an update of the body without an actual update of the browser document so external libraries must be forced to reinitialize related elements.
To achieve this, we can move the code that initializes type-tel inputs into an event-listener for the livewire:navigated event:
document.addEventListener('livewire:navigated', () => {

    const elementsTypePhone = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=tel]");

    elementsTypePhone.forEach(element => {

        // console.log ("element: ", element);

        const iti = intlTelInput(element, {

            initialCountry: "bh",
            strictMode: true,
            separateDialCode: true,
            onlyCountries: ['bh', 'sa', 'ae', 'qa', 'kw', 'om', 'us', 'gb'],
            utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@21.1.1/build/js/utils.js",
        });
    });
});



Thank you for your gracious response. However, I've attempted to use wire:ignore within a wrapped , yet it appears to be ineffective. Upon researching wire:ignore in Livewire 3, I discovered there are known issues associated with its functionality in this version.

It's strange, I tested your code with my modification and it works well, the dropdown is handled correctly and doesn't stop working. Can you explain better what problems you encounter?

My code is the same as provided earlier. so there is no major change just fixed the attributes and added wire:ignore in a div and wrap it around the input field. it behaves the same. However, upon submitting the form for an update, the JavaScript functionalities ceased, leaving the field devoid of its intended functionality.
One noteworthy point is the utilization of Vite for compiling both JavaScript and CSS. All JavaScript functionalities are consolidated within the app.js file.

Yes, I have used npm run build to compile the assets. -- Note that inserting wire:ignore in the  doesn't work because intl-tel-input manipulates it, an outer tag is needed. At this point it might be useful to see your  form

Note: to include properly  the css I have used import 'intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css' in app.js

Thank you for the kind response.
Sure, this is the JS in my app.js
import intlTelInput from 'intl-tel-input';
document.addEventListener('livewire:init', () => {
    const elementsWithPhoneId = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=tel]');
    elementsWithPhoneId.forEach(element => {

        const iti = intlTelInput(element, {
            initialCountry: "bh",
            strictMode: true,
            separateDialCode: true,
            onlyCountries: ['bh', 'sa', 'ae', 'qa', 'kw', 'om', 'us', 'gb'],
            utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@21.1.1/build/js/utils.js",
        });
    });
});

This is my component in blade template
<div class="w-full py-2 lg:w-1/2 md:w-1/2 px-2 grid grid-cols-1" >
    <label for="inputC1P1" class="w-full font-medium py-1">Primary Phone : <span class="text-red-600"> *</span></label>
    <div wire:ignore>
        <input
            type="tel"
            id="inputC1P1"
            class="@error('C1PrimaryContact') bg-red-200 @enderror form-input border border-1 rounded-md w-full my-1 border-gray-300 shadow-md hover:transition-all"
            placeholder="3344 5566"
            wire:model.blur="C1PrimaryContact"
            required
        />
    </div>
    <div>
        @error('C1PrimaryContact') <p class="text-red-600 font-light text-xs antialiased italic">{{ $message }}</p>  @enderror
    </div>
</div>


Everything seems fine. Since we have wire:model.blur, the input value is sent immediately to the backend when it loses focus: what happens when you exit the fied? (for example using the Tab key) In this case is the layout preserved or broken? Do you have a form that wraps the inputs? Can I see  it? How did you include the CSS?

This is how it looks when it is freshly loaded
link
After submitting the form turn it into
link
CSS & JS added like this
@vite('resources/css/app.css')         <title>{{ $title ?? 'Page Title' }} - {{env('APP_NAME')}}</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.3.0/datepicker.min.js"></script>         @vite('resources/js/app.js')
On pressing Tab it doesn't break.

If wire:ignore didn't work, exiting the field with Tab should break the view (due to  the .blur modifier) so I suspect that there is some other element that create problems on the form submit. You should post the relevant code of the form, not the images. I see that you are using Flowbite, it sometimes has malfunctions with Livewire. I still can't see intlTelInput.css

I removed the Flowbite and tested it, It still has the same issue, intleTelInput.css I have imported it in app.css like @import 'intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css';

Here is the form link on github link

I saw your code and found the problem, I edited my answer with some fixes to make

Very well! If you want you can accept thw answer and close the  question
